# How can I scroll on my Page when my Dialog Component has been opened

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, material-design, styled-components

I want to scroll on the background, when my dialog component opens up. By default, you cannot scroll when the dialog appears. How can I scroll in the background ?

Following is the Code:-

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
    makeStyles,
    Grid,
    Button,
    Dialog,
    DialogActions,
    DialogTitle,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import ShoppingCartIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ShoppingCart';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';

const styles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        position: 'fixed',
        bottom: '0 ',
        left: '0',
        right: '0',
        boxShadow: '0 0 6px rgb(0 0 0 / 70%)',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        height: '63px',
    },
    textStyle: {
        fontFamily: 'Comfortaa',
    },
    icon: {
        color: theme.palette.primary.dark,
    },

    btn: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.dark,
        color: 'white',
        fontFamily: 'Comfortaa',
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.dark,
        },
    },

    title: {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        borderBottom: '1px solid #e5e5e5',
    },
    closeIcon: {
        color: theme.palette.primary.light,
        '&:hover': {
            color: 'black',
        },
    },

    dialogStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
    },

    dialogContainer: {
        opacity: 0,
    },
    dialogTitle: {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        borderBottom: '1px solid #e5e5e5',
    },
}));

const CartAppBar: React.FC = () => {
    const classes = styles();
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleClickOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };
    const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    };
    return (
        <>
            <Grid
                item
                container
                direction='row'
                justify='space-around'
                alignItems='center'
                className={classes.root}
                xs={12}
            >
                <div>
                    <ShoppingCartIcon
                        fontSize='large'
                        classes={{ root: classes.icon }}
                        onClick={handleClickOpen}
                    />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Button
                        className={classes.btn}
                        type='submit'
                        onClick={() => {
                            return (window.location.href = '/checkout');
                        }}
                    >
                        Checkout
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </Grid>

            <Dialog
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                aria-labelledby='alert-dialog-title'
                aria-describedby='alert-dialog-description'
                maxWidth='md'
                fullWidth
                classes={{
                    paper: classes.dialogStyle,
                    container: classes.dialogContainer,
                }}
                scroll='paper'
            >
                <DialogTitle className={classes.dialogTitle}>
                    <CloseIcon
                        onClick={handleClose}
                        classes={{ root: classes.closeIcon }}
                    />
                </DialogTitle>
                {/* Footer */}
                {/* <DialogActions className={classes.footer}>
                    <Button classes={{ root: classes.btn }}>Add To Cart</Button>
                </DialogActions> */}
            </Dialog>
        </>
    );
};

export default CartAppBar;
```

[image: Photo]

As you can see in the photo, there's opacity in the background and you cannot scroll. I want to override this and make the background scrollable

Comment: I think passing the `disableScrollLock` prop should work for your case. [Source](https://material-ui.com/api/modal/#props)

Answer (score 0):

use disableScrollLock as prop will help